# How to search and count a value in array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a array named theRooms[] and it contains 10 rooms. Some of them are singleCount, which have a single bed and some doubleCount, which have double bed.
I need to find how many singleCount rooms i have in the theRooms[]

```
public int getSingleCount()
   {  
      int singleCount
      for(int i = 0; i < theRooms.length; i++)  
      {
         if (theRooms[i] == 1)
            singleCount++
      }
      return singleCount;
   }
```

Comment: I've down-voted because there is no evidence you've tried anything before asking. Your question is also very unclear. A code sample would probably help address both those issues.

Comment: this is what i have tried but it is not working: 
   public int getSingleCount()
   {  
      int singleCount
      for(int i = 0; i < theRooms.length; i++)  
      {
         if (theRooms[i] == 1)
            singleCount++
      }
      return singleCount;
   }

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. Can you explain why it doesn't work as you wish?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to iterate through the array.

```
int count = 0;
for (Room room : theRooms)
    if (room.isSingleCount())
        count++;
```

Comment: Needs more brackets :-P

Comment: @Duncan While I prefer braces, this will work without them since there is only one statement inside the `for` and also the `if`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog My comment was more of a joke :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming theRooms contains an array of Room objects that have a method called bedCount which returns a number corresponding to the number of people it can house.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < theRooms.length; i++) {
  count += theRooms[i].bedCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have method count in your object rooms, then you can do the following

```
int count = 0;

for (rooms room : theRooms){
    if (room.count() == 1)
        count++;
}

System.out.println(count);
```